# OpenSCAD syntax: modify value in vector/list/array

Tags: openscad

Note: official documentation calls these "vectors", official cheat sheet calls these "lists", and are equivalent in other languages with "arrays". I will refer to them as vectors for now.

I have a vector with values in it, and I'm trying to modify a single vector element.
For example I want to to multiply the first element by 2:

```
vector1 = [10,20,30,40];
vector1[0] = vector1[0] * 2
```

What is the proper way to do it?

Optional: is there any guide or book where these kind of basics are explained?
I'm coming from C/C++, and I'm having a terrible time with script languages like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenSCAD variables are more like constants](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/General#Variables) than variables in many other languages.  Generally, you need to make a new value rather than modify an existing one.

For lists, you can use a list comprehension:

```
vector1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
vector2 = [2*vector1[0], each [for (i=[1:len(vector1)-1]) vector1[i]]];
```

OpenSCAD is a functional programming language.  It requires a different mindset than what need for procedural languages like C and C++.